# Hide all properties of given type in Springdoc Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I’m using **springdoc-openapi-ui** to generate an OpenAPI definition. It generates properties from functions annotated with `javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue`. I don't want it to do so.

I know about the `hidden = true` option but don't want to use it as I prefer to have it set globally (e.g. don't generate properties for `javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue` type)

Do you have any ideas how it can be done?